# Do cordova plugins work with capacitor (ionic)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

When I add plugin : ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage for use https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/storage Is there any trouble here? I am using capacitor. What if I add the cordova plugins?.

when add ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage

```
[WARN] About to integrate your app with Cordova.
       
       We now recommend Capacitor (https://ion.link/capacitor) as the official native runtime for Ionic. To learn about 
       the differences between Capacitor and Cordova, see these docs[1]. For a getting started guide, see these docs[2].
       
       [1]: https://ion.link/capacitor-differences-with-cordova-docs
       [2]: https://ion.link/capacitor-using-with-ionic-docs
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible to use Cordova plugins with Capacitor. There is no guarantee they will be fully compatible, but you can install and use them in your project.

However, you don't have to run `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-name`, since that will effectively initialize Cordova for your app, which is not what you want.

Instead, install the Cordova plugin and sync Capacitor:

```
npm install cordova-plugin-name
npx cap sync
```

If the plugin is from Ionic Native, you also have to install the Ionic native package before the Cordova plugin:

```
npm install @ionic-native/plugin-name
npm install cordova-plugin-name
npx cap sync
```

See more information here: [Capacitor - Using Cordova Plugins and Ionic Native](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v2/cordova/using-cordova-plugins)

---

**Update 15/01/2021**

I have been using this in actual projects for a while and I have verified it works all fine, however, there is a common problem you may run into when building with AndroidX. Some Cordova plugins still use the old compatibility libraries and may fail to build.

The solution is using [Jetifier](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jetifier) to upgrade the packages as required. Install Jetifier using `npm i jetifier --save-dev` to add it as a dev dependency in your package.json.

After running `npx cap add android` to generate the Android project if it did not exist yet, run `npx cap sync android` and finally `npx jetifier` before running Gradle to build the app.

Jetifier will identify the packages that require an upgrade.

Hope this helps out with some of the troubleshooting.